# AngularJS single select filtering is not working for Name, Description and Field4 checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have filtering like following: means, if I select `multiple checkboxes`(say: one checkbox from `Name` and one checkbox from `Description` dropdowns), then those respective matched data is coming fine of `Name` and `Description` columns, and similarly for other selections also(like with `Description` and `Field4` and `Field4` and Name `dropdowns`).

If I select all three checkboxes from all dropdowns(like `name 1`, `description 1` and `field4 1` then it's matched data is coming fine of `Name`, `Description` and `Field4` columns.

But what I need is now: the data is not filtering with the single checkbox  or individual checkbox selection(Like: if I select any either `Name` or `Description` or `field4` dropdown checkbox, then the selected checkbox related data is not coming). So that I can filter the data with three cases: single selection, any two dropdown checkbox selection, all three dropdown checkbox selection.

Code is given below and created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/mstxfc9f/3/).

How can I do this ? Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated a bit more code to get it working.

```
$scope.filterItems = function(item) {
        if ($scope.pagedItems.name !== undefined && $scope.pagedItems.description !== undefined && $scope.pagedItems.name !== "false" && $scope.pagedItems.description !== "false") {
        if(item.name === $scope.pagedItems.name && item.description === $scope.pagedItems.description) return true;
    } else {
            if (item.name === $scope.pagedItems.name) return true;
        if (item.description === $scope.pagedItems.description) return true;
        if ((item.description.indexOf($scope.pagedItems.description) > -1 && 
             $scope.pagedItems.description !== '')) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Select Name<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='pagedItems.name' data-ng-true-value='name 1' data-ng-false-value='false' /> name1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='pagedItems.name' data-ng-true-value='name 2' data-ng-false-value='false' /> name2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='pagedItems.name' data-ng-true-value='name 3' data-ng-false-value='false' /> name3</li>
    </ul>
</div><br><br>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Select Description <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='pagedItems.description' data-ng-true-value='description 1' data-ng-false-value='false' /> description 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='pagedItems.description' data-ng-true-value='description 2' data-ng-false-value='false' /> description 2</li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

By changing from nameOne to name (same for description) I was able to simplify your if statements and make the combined match work without a gigantic if statement.

I updated your fiddle, you can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/selten98/v5L7jq92/3/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes it is working(second scenario) with name 1 and description 1(matched data), but failing first scenario(like: if I select only name 1, then "name 1" data should display, it is not coming now ?

Comment: See the update of my post. This does what you want. Please keep the HTML uniform (e.g. keep the false values all the same, don't change it between them. I changed it now all to false so I can get rid of it).

Comment: yes it is working fine now as per my requirement. Thank you very much for your help really !!

Comment: I have one query that if I add one more dropdown for Field4, then this time individual dropdown selection is not working ? But other two cases like: select all checkboxes(like from name 1, description 1, Field4 1 then matched data is coming fine) and any two selection(like name 1, description 1 or description 1, field4 1 or field4 1, name 1) then matched data is coming fine. Kindly let me know that how can I get individual selection too along with the above cases. I have modified the question and description with the Fiddle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get what you mean

Comment: i have got it now what I made mistake. some naming conventions I gave are wrong. Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: solution is available at: https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/mstxfc9f/6/, it may helpful to anyone.